# How to use consul in dev environment

Tags: microservices, consul

Suppose I've got services `A` and `B`. Both of them are deployed to `test` server and connected to Consul.

When I start service `A` on my local machine it will read data from consul and interact with service `B` deployed on `test` server. 
How can I make service `A` to interact with service `B` on the local machine if it's also running?

I thought to run local Consul instance and proxy missing requests (configuration and service discovery) to test server consul but I didn't find any info about it.

How can / should I configure my local environment with Consul?

Answer (score 1):

Steps for configuring consul on local environment :

1. install consul on local 
   https://www.consul.io/downloads.html
2. `consul agent -dev` - command used to run consul on local
3. You can use git2consul tool for reading the config from the local git repository, like

```
git2consul --config <path to git2consul file>
```

https://github.com/breser/git2consul

Comment: I know how to start consul. The question is how to mix it with local + test server development?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid the usage of service B running in the test environment you should make your local service B to register whit a different name into the consul server like C and also change you local service A to consume it.

This way you would have registered into consul two instances of service A, one instance of service B and one instance of service C and.